# How to prevent the use of urllib2 package in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to do the same thing below, but without using the urllib2 package.
I am trying to web scrape a URL (not exactly the one shown below).
Must have headers for security reasons.

```
URL = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=test'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.4'}
req = urllib2.Request(URL, headers=hdr)
pag = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pag, "lxml")
all_tables = soup.find_all('table')
right_table = soup.find_all('table')[1]
```

I have tried looking this up in stack overflow, but I can only find solutions using urllib2.
I have reasons for not wanting to use urllib2

Is there any way to do this without using urllib2?
I'm using python 2.7

Thanks.

Comment: use requests http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ is based on urllib3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

URL = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=test'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.4'}
req = requests.get(URL, headers=hdr)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
all_tables = soup.find_all('table')
right_table = soup.find_all('table')[1]
```

Comment: I believe that you can provide some explanation or comments for your answer to make it even better.